# C++ calls destructor immediately, even when rule of three is followed

Tags: c++, windows, destructor

Here is my following code. Once the constructor of A is complete, it immediately calls the ~B and deletes the allocated variable. I have the copy constructor and assignment constructor. Should I implement rule of five to prevent this?

EDIT: I have edited my copy and assignment constructor implementations, but still the destructor is being called.

```
class B
{
public:
    C **table;
B() 
{
   table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE]();
}
B(const B& other)
{
   table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE];
   memcpy(table, other.table, sizeof(C *)* TABLE_SIZE);
}
B& operator = (const B& other)
{
  if (this == &other)
  {
     return *this;
  }
  delete[] table;
  table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE];
  memcpy(table, other.table, sizeof(C *)* TABLE_SIZE);
  return *this;
}
~B() 
{
    delete[] table;
}
}

class A
{
protected:
   B funcA();
private:
   B _b; 
}

A::A()
{
   this->_b = this->funcA();
   // calls ~B here and destroys table
}
```

Comment: You are doing more copying than you think when you do `_b = func()`.  The return of `funcA` produces a `B` object, then you assign that temporary `B` object to `_b`,  Also, your "rule of 3" implementation is seriously broken.

Comment: Well, for one, your copy constructor isn't correct. It's not actually *copying* the table, it's just making two `B` objects that both point to the same table. That's a pretty bad ownership problem; If either is deleted, the table is deleted. Your assignment overload has the same problem. You basically just duplicated the naive shallow copy.

Comment: Also, it makes it easier if you moved the (albeit wrong) code in the assignment operator to the copy constructor, and let the assignment operator implement copy/swap (once the copy constructor code is fixed).

Comment: To elaborate on @PaulMcKenzie 's point, read about the [canonical implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator) of `operator=`.

Answer (score 3):

You do have the copy constructor and copy assignment operator implemented, but *incorrectly.* You implemented them to do exactly what the defaults do, which is of course wrong for your case of owning a dynamically allocated memory stored in a raw pointer. The Rule of Three of course means that you must implement them *consistently.*

In your case, this most likely means the copy operations must deep-copy the `C` object:

```
class B
{
public:
  C *table;

  B() : table(new C()) {}

  B(const B& other) : table(new C(*other.table)) {}

  B& operator = (const B& other)
  {
    if (this == &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete table;
    table = new C(*other.table);
    return *this;
  }

  ~B() 
  {
    delete table;
  }
};
```

Notice that you default constructor wouldn't even compile - you were assigning a `C*` into a `C**`. I changed the code above to use a single allocation (and single-item `delete`) instead of an array. If you do have an array, the principle stays the same.

Of course, it's preferable to follow the Rule of Zero instead of the Rule of Three—use an appropriate smart pointer if possible. If your real use case *is* an array, that would be turning `table` into a `std::vector<C>`. Then you wouldn't have to supply the copy operations or destructor at all.

If you actually want to *share* one `C` among all copies of `B`, then you'll need to use an appropriate shared-ownership smart pointer instead, such as `std::shared_ptr<C>`.

Comment: Alternatively, if shared-table semantics are really what you want (copying/assigning a `B` results in two `B`'s pointing to the same table instance), then it needs to be some form of shared pointer rather than a raw one.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, it is a typo in the code. It is actually an array, this is my default constructor: 

     B() : table(new C *[TABLE_SIZE]()) {}

As per your suggestion, i modified the copy constructor:

    B(const B& other) : table(new (C *[TABLE_SIZE])(*other.table)) {}

but I have this error "an array can only be initialized with an initializer-list"

Comment: @user759913 If it's actually an array, you'll have to copy it manually.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the right way to copy?  B(const B& other) 
 {
  table = new C*[TABLE_SIZE]();
  for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
  {
   table[i] = other.table[i];
  }
 }

Comment: @user759913 That, or `std::copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the temporary instance returned by `funcA` should be destroyed, that's normal and expected. The fact that your code is not functioning as a result means that your copy constructor and assignment operator are not functioning correctly.

But more fundamentally, you're violating several more important rules than the Rule of Three. You're failing to re-use the existing solution of `std::vector`. You're violating SRP by tying together memory management and whatever else `B` does when it's at home. You're failing to use RAII to manage your internal resources- a big exception safety fail.

Basically, the core problem is that you're even attempting to perform these operations. Don't. Just use `std::vector<C*>` and make the compiler and Standard library vendor implement them for you. They will save you a lot of code, and furthermore, they will be correct in ways that I'm going to guess that you don't know exist yet, like exception safety. The Rule of Three and the Rule of Five (which didn't even exist long enough to become a rule) are both vastly inferior to the Rule of Zero.

Here's `B` but implemented correctly:

```
class B {
public:
    std::vector<C*> table;
    B() : table(TABLE_SIZE) {}
};
```

Simple, ain't it?

As a side note, I don't know where you're getting your learning materials, but you should burn with fire any source so seriously outdated as to recommend self-assignment checks, and well, any of that code. May as well tell you that 640k of memory is all you'll ever need.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is:

```
A::A()
{
    this->_b = this->funcA();
    // calls ~B here and destroys table
}
```

The comment is correct, although the table being destroyed is the table in the temporary object, not the table of `_b`. Since you fixed your copy-assignment operator this means that `_b`'s table is fine.

The list of steps in executing this constructor is:

1. Call default constructor of `_b`
2. Call `funcA`, returning a temporary object of type `B`
3. Call `_b` 's assignment operator with that temporary object
4. Destruct the temporary object.

The constructor could be improved by supplying `funcA()` directly as initializer for `_b`, instead of first default-constructing `_b` then using its assignment operator. (But there is still a temporary object destruction).

There may also be another temporary object created and destroyed in the process of returning from the function, depending on your compiler settings. (usually there would not be).